# Is it possible to create a fieldtype that creates a many to many relationship between two entry sections?

Tags: entries, relations

So, for example:

Say I have two sections:

```
- Recipes
- Ingredients
```

Recipes can have many ingredients. Ingredients can have many recipes.

If I'm editing a Recipe, I can edit the ingredients. This updates the relationship so that when I edit ingredients it can show the associated recipes (and they are editable from the ingredients as well).

Is this possible with Craft?

Thanks!

====== EDIT ======

Just to make this more clear. What I'm trying to do is create a Many to Many relationship between two Sections of Entries so there is an association between the two that works both ways.

Another example of this would be if you have a User with many Roles. I can manage which Users belong to which Roles from the Roles section, and/or I could manage which Roles a User belongs to from the Users section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's still a few kinks to work out, but I developed a plugin that solves this problem using Craft's native Many to Many relationship that already exists.

Basically, I've created a field type that links the relationship from the other side of things and allows you to add entries to it.

You can find it here:
https://github.com/page-8/craft-manytomany

Thanks [@Brandon Kelly](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/users/9/brandon-kelly) for the help and guidance.

Comment: Great Peter, nice work! Go ahead and submit that to [Straight Up Craft](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins), if you haven't already... I'm sure others would find it useful as well! :)

Comment: Good call Lindsey. Done and done.

Answer (score 6):

You can assign ingredients to recipes using the built-in [Entries](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/entries-fields) field type.

Then, to view which recipes an ingredient is used on, check out the [Introvert](https://github.com/iainurquhart/craft_introvert) plugin. It gives you a new field type that can be used to simply show reverse relationships, also providing links to edit those other entries.

Comment: Thanks for the Response Brandon. This is about half way there.

The client has requested the editing be a two way street, meaning that they be able to add and remove associated recipes from the ingredients edit screen.

This is beneficial because say they were to add a new ingredient, they can quickly associate it with all applicable recipes rather than having to open each individual recipe and add it there.

Comment: Ah, yeah. Currently that’s not possible with Introvert. Feature request!